# Answers that are meant as a joke

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

So I have <strike>[this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96068/36641)</strike> (edit: answer was removed and added as comment to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95875/36641)) which in itself seems to be an attempt to answer [the question asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95838/36641).
Problem with this answer is that the answer is totally false. This could very well be because the person didn't play the game or is just false informed.
What I'm concerned about is that, after I pointed out that the answer is false, the person that made that answer commented that "it was a joke".

Is it correct to flag the answer as "Not an answer" because of it beeing meant as a joke?

Seeing as the question or answer might be edited I will quote the relevent parts of the question and the given answer here.
The part of the question beeing "answered":

> - How do enemies detect by movement sound (when you are not in their vision)?
>
>   - Will walking or crouch walking lessen sound (compared to sprinting)?
>   - Do 'noisier' floor attract more attention, when you walk/sprint on them? (e.g. walking on a 'noisy' metal floor, compared to walking on grass)

The answer:

> Making sounds while running does not affect stealth.
>   You can shoot a gun at an Army wall and they will not notice.

The comment from the answerer after me pointing out the answer is false:

> Dude, shut up, it was a joke

Comment: As a sidenote, welcome to meta!  This is the correct location to ask this sort of question.

Comment: As another sidenote, you've got an awesome default gravatar!

Comment: @RavenDreamer [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/swastikas-in-fractal-images)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answers can include jokes, but jokes can't be the whole answer.

What to do with joke answers? Downvote them. Flag them. If the joke is particularly brilliant we'll promote them to comments on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Why was the answer and its comments added as comments to Strike's question? None of them are particularly great jokes.

Comment: @kotekzot Because in my eyes it was a reply to Strike's question and not even remotely something worthy of being called a "joke". :P

Comment: @kotekzot and badp: If I remember correctly, the removed answer existed before I made my answer, so it couldn't be a comment to my answer.

Comment: @Strike actually your answers preceded the deleted one by almost 2 days. To my eyes though the deleted answer is simply noise and adds absolutely nothing of value, but I suppose there isn't much harm in it staying as a comment.

Comment: @kotekzot Well, my memory fails me then. Also I agree with letting it stay as a comment.